# When using Angular with SignalR, how do I notify a controller when a change is made to an object in a service?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I have a reasonably simple Angular app with four controllers and two services. One service stores data and shares it around with the other controllers, something like this:

```
var DataService = function($http) {
    this.testData = [];
}    
MyApp.service('DataService', ["$http", DataService]);
```

and the other service contains the client-side SignalR methods, something like this:

```
var HubService = function(DataService) {    
    this.testHub = $.connection.TestHub;
    this.connectionStatus = [];

    this.connectToHub = function(callback) {
        var self = this;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            self.connectionStatus.push(1);
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    };  

    this.getSomeData = function (node, callback) {        
        this.testHub.server.getSomeData(node).done(function (response) {            
            if (callback) { callback(); }         
        });
    };  

    this.testHub.client.addData = function(serverData) {
        DataService.testData.push(serverData)   
    };  
}

MyApp.service('HubService', ["DataService", HubService]);
```

where the server-side hub method is something like

```
public class TestHub : Hub {
     public void GetSomeData(Node node) {
        var data = _queries.getSomeDataFromAServer();
        Clients.All.addData(data);
     }
}
```

Now this all works fine, I inject the DataService and HubService into the controllers and I can call the HubService.getSomeData() method and that calls the server-side method and that then in turn calls the client-side SignalR method and the DataService.testData object is updated.

The **problem** is that the controllers are not notified of this change until the next $digest cycle, which is usually some sort of UI event. I need the controllers to be notified immediately. I know that usually I can just call $scope.$apply() to manually trigger the $digest cycle, but as the service method is being called directly from the server-side method there's no way to use $scope.

What do I do? How can I make Angular watch a service object for changes from another service, or how can I trigger a $digest cycle across all controllers from a service-method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be not answer but you get mechanism how you achieve it.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('myService', function($rootScope) {
  var data = 0;
  var id = 0;

  var increment = function() {
    data = data + 1;
    $rootScope.$apply();
    console.log("Incrementing data", data);
  };

  this.start = function() {
    id = setInterval(increment, 500) ;

  };

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(id);
  };

  this.getData = function() { return data; };

}).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.service = myService;
  $scope.controllerData = 0;

  $scope.start = function() {
    myService.start();
  };

  $scope.stop = function() {
    myService.stop();
  };

  $scope.$watch('service.getData()', function(newVal) {

    console.log("New Data", newVal);
    $scope.controllerData = newVal;
  });
});
```

Comment: you can use apply to explicitly call the cycle.

Comment: So there are times when Angular complains about $scope.$apply() saying that the $digest cycle is already in process. I fix this by wrapping it around if (!$scope.$$phase) {$scope.$apply();}. Do I have to do some equivalent with $rootScope?